# Why this SQL insert into table statement does not work in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, insert, oracle11g

I get a ORAC 0936 when ExcuteNonQuery executes.  I guess my problem is the VALUES section of my SQL. Thanks in advance for your help

```
public int NewFunction(int UserID, string fName, string fDescription, string connectionStr)
        {
            OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionStr);
            try
            {
                //PLease Note that User ID and  fDescription are passed into the function as  
//parameters
                connection.Open();

                OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();

                OracleTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
                command.Transaction = transaction;
                        string LoadedFileName = @WfName;//Fd.FileName;
               //read the xaml content from file 
                command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO XYZ(ID, NAME , F_SCRIPT) VALUES (@UserID, @fDescription, EMPTY_CLOB())";

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                transaction.Commit();
               }
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//*****************************************************
//OK, thanks for all the replies.  This is how I got it to work, using other posts from stackckoverflow for other questions. Please note that fDescription and USerID are being passed to the function.

command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO IMS_Workflow (ID, NAME , F_SCRIPT) VALUES ('" + UserID + "', '" + WfDescription + "', EMPTY_CLOB())";

Comment: I see no indication that you're populating the parameters... you're never using the `fName` or `fDescription` parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. fDescription is passed to the function.  fName is a superfluous variable which I should not even have had in my code.  I found my answer and I added it to my question. please fee free to comment on it, since that is what I found to be working. Whether it is a preferred way or not, I am interested to know. Thanks again.

Comment: Well `fDescription` passed to the *method* - but it's not passed to the *database* at all. Your workaround invites SQL injection attacks, *please* don't use it.

Comment: Thanks. So how do I do it otherwise?  I would appreciate the correct syntax.

Comment: See my answer. If that doesn't work, please give *details* rather than just the "it did not work" that you left on the other answer.

Comment: I get an ORA-01036  when I do the following:

Comment: command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO XYZ(ID, NAME , F_SCRIPT) VALUES (@UserID , @fDescription, EMPTY_CLOB())";
 //
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", UserID.ToString());
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fDescription", fDescription.ToString()); 
               //       
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: Have you tried the code in my answer, using `:` instead of `@`? (And not including the prefix in the parameter `Add` call).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original code looks like it's trying to use parameterized SQL:

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO XYZ(ID, NAME , F_SCRIPT) VALUES (@UserID, @fDescription, EMPTY_CLOB())";
```

... but you never set the *values* for the parameters, and it's using SQL Server style names (`@` prefix instead of `:`). You need to declare the parameters properly, and giving them values, e.g.

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO XYZ(ID, NAME , F_SCRIPT) VALUES (:UserID, :fDescription, EMPTY_CLOB())";
command.Parameters.Add("UserId", OracleType.Number).Value = userId;
command.Parameters.Add("fDescription", OracleType.NVarChar).Value = fDescription;
```

(It's possible that the prefix of `@` would work as well; I'm only going by examples in documentation.)

Your workaround is to embed the values directly into your SQL. **Don't do this**. You're inviting [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: Thank you so much. Your suggestipon worked.  Could you possibly tell  me the correct syntax for a select statement. I could put it in a separet question if you would like.  command.CommandText = "SELECT F_SCRIPT FROM XYZ WHERE ID='" + UserID + "' FOR UPDATE";

Comment: @user1298925: What have you tried, based on my existing answer? You need to be willing to do some work for yourself, and read around a topic. Do you not understand why you should *not* include values directly within the SQL?

Comment: Actually, I have been trying to come up with the answer myself but I have not tested it yet. I was thinking by the time I try my different solutions maybe the right answer would  be  here too.    Here is my untested solution.                                                               command.CommandText = "SELECT F_SCRIPT FROM XYZ WHERE ID=:UserID  AND " +" NAME =:fDescription" + " FOR UPDATE ";
                command.Parameters.Add("UserID", OracleType.Number).Value = UserID;
                command.Parameters.Add("fDescription", OracleType.NVarChar).Value = fDescription;

Answer (score 3):

I may be missing something but I don't see where you're adding the parameters @UserID or @fDescription to your command object's parameters collection.  Add those and I suspect you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you. I did add parameters and it did  not work.  My problem was with the syntax, I found out.. I will update my question with the solution I found and please fee free to comment on it, since that is what I found to be working. Whether it is a ppreferred way or not, I am interested to know. Thanks again.